# How to iterate array inside array in ionic3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

[image]I am trying to get a list of products and I'm running into an issue due to the fact that it's an array and inside array multiple array is used how to iterate array inside the object i have tried but show object object in html tell m anyone how to iterate array?

```js
/*
  @Copyright Notice:
  @(#)
  @Type: TS 
  @For:  create-accont.html.
  @Description : getInitiallyCategoryProducts function for get the list of products
*/
getInitiallyCategortProducts(categoryKeyId , subCategoryKeyId){
  let self       = this;

  if(categoryKeyId != undefined) {
    let object = {
      categoryKeyId    : categoryKeyId,
      subCategoryKeyId : subCategoryKeyId
    }

    //show the laoder after load the products
    let loading = self.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Loading..."
    });
    loading.present();

    //call function for checkDesingNumberInGCP for check desing number is exist or not  
    self.sellerAuthData.getProductsByCategoryWiseInGCP(function(isSuccess, data) {
      if(data.isSuccess && data.UserProductList) {
        self.sellerProductListViaCategory = data.UserProductList;

        //Disable the loader after response is generated
        loading.dismiss();
      } else {
        console.log("isCreated false from the API");
      }
    }, object);
  } else {
    console.log("object is undeined or null");
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-list style=" margin-top: 48px;">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let userProduct of sellerProductListViaCategory">
    <ul class='imageList'>
      <span *ngFor="let productSet of userProduct.sellerProductSetDto">
         <li *ngFor="let imageURL of productSet.setImageURLList">
          <img src="{{imageURL}}">
        </li> 
        <ion-icon ios="ios-close-circle" md="md-close-circle"></ion-icon>
      </span>
    </ul>
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Add data of list of products as well

Comment: i don't understand sir what are u saying?

Comment: What are you getting in `sellerProductListViaCategory`. Add that JSON/Array here.

Comment: sir here sellerProductListViaCategory is array that is get from the API sir check  my updated fiddle ?

Comment: What content and in what format you are getting this array?

Comment: Sir check updated fiddle i have print array fomat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168265/discussion-between-kapil-soni-and-vicjordan).